# Associations in data model, how one row can point to different foreign keys?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

**The Case:**

I'm really stuck in thinking about the proper way for linking two tables in my data model, consider this example (which is abstracted from the problem)

Say that I have:

- some model called '**Attachment**' which contains 'attachment_id','attachment_title',.... etc,
- and another model called '**Question**' which contains 'question_id', 'attachment_id' (foreign) , 'question_option1', 'question_option2','question_option2','correct_answer',  etc.

I already know that each "question" may have an attachment with the question, so we have these relationships so far:

in question model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Attachment' => array(
        'className' => 'Attachment',
        'foreignKey' => 'attachment_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
    ),
```

and in attachment model I have :

```
var $hasOne = array(
    'Question' => array(
        'className' => 'Question',
        'foreignKey' => 'attachment_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
```

**The Problem :**

Then a new requirement has arisen : put images for the every option in 'Question' , so instead we can show images not the text, which means that we add new rows in 'Question' table (at least what I did) that called 'question_option1_attachment', 'question_option2_attachment', 'question_option3_attachment' , and these cells will contain a foreign key that points to an attachment_id.

surely this didn't work for me :

```
'foreignKey' => array('attachment_id', 'question_option1_attachment', 'question_option2_attachment', 'question_option3_attachment') ...
```

**The Question :**

How to do the association between One question that has many rows point to different foreign keys ?
what do you suggest, do I need to redefine the whole association somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

As the case specified above, I think so you will be required to create another table that hold the data that defines the mapping between different questions and foreign keys.

This table will only have the ids mapped with the questions and while making a call to the model you will be required to take the table into consideration so check what are the keys associated with the question. These will have multiple entries for a question so you will have to use the JOINS to get the appropriate data.